# Can't find a combination of keywords on an xml page using python and beautiful soup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I wanna find a  tag where two keywords are present in. For example, I wanna find a  tag that includes an occurrence of 'Yankee' **AND** 'duck'. Code is below:

```
        elif len(keywords) == 2:
            keyword1 = keywords[0]
            keyword2 = keywords[1]

            print("Searching for product...")
            keywordLinkFound = False
            while keywordLinkFound is False:
                html = self.driver.page_source
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
                try:
                    keywordLink = soup.find('loc', text=re.compile(keyword1 + keyword2)).text
                    return keywordLink
                except AttributeError:
                    print("Product not found on site, retrying...")
                    time.sleep(monitorDelay)
                    self.driver.refresh()
                break
```

And here is the xml i am trying to get:

```
<url>
<loc>
  https://packershoes.com/products/copy-of-382-new-balance-m999jtc-1
</loc>
<lastmod>2018-12-04T21:49:25-05:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<image:image>
<image:loc>
  https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0208/5268/products/NB999JTC-2_4391df07-a3a2-4c82-87b3-49d776096473.jpg?v=1543851653
</image:loc>
  <image:title>NEW BALANCE M999JTC "MADE IN USA"</image:title>
</image:image>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
  https://packershoes.com/products/copy-of-382-packer-x-new-era-new-york-yankee-duck-canvas-1
</loc>
<lastmod>2018-12-06T14:39:37-05:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<image:image>
<image:title>
  NEW ERA JAPAN 59FIFTY NEW YORK YANKEES "DUCK CANVAS"
</image:title>
</image:image>
</url>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keyword1 + keyword2` is the string `yankeeduck`, so you're searching for that string, and it won't match when the two words are not connected like that. You need to allow anything between them, as well as recognize them in the opposite order. So the regexp should be:

```
yankee.*duck|duck.*yankee
```

Therefore, the code should be:

```
regexp = "%s.*%s|%s.%s"%(keyword1, keyword2, keyword2, keyword1)
keywordLink = soup.find('loc', text=re.compile(regexp)).text
```

And in case the keywords contain characters that are special in regexp, you should escape them:

```
keyword1 = re.escape(keywords[0])
keyword2 = re.escape(keywords[1])
```

Comment: What I was trying to do the same thing for an <image:title> tag like the xml code above. I tried the same thing, but it did not pick it up

Comment: Maybe an issue with case-sensitivity?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks!
Therefore, the code should be:

```
regexp = "%s.*%s|%s.%s"%(keyword1, keyword2, keyword2, keyword1)
keywordLink = soup.find('loc', text=re.compile(regexp)).text
```

And in case the keywords contain characters that are special in regexp, you should escape them:

```
keyword1 = re.escape(keywords[0])
keyword2 = re.escape(keywords[1])
```